# Possible to have status bar icon without (visible) window icon?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons, taskbar

Having a resizable WinForms form and setting the [`Form.ShowIcon property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showicon.aspx) to `true`, I get this (expected) result:

[image]
*(An icon in the main window and an icon in the task bar)*

Setting the `ShowIcon` property to `false` and keeping the actual [`Form.Icon` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.icon.aspx) with the icon, I get this result:

[image]
*(No icon in the form, a default icon in the task bar)*

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]
*(No icon in the form but still an icon in the task bar)*

**My question:**

Is it possible to hide a form icon in the form's caption bar only while keeping it visible in all other areas? (task bar, showing when cycling with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, Task Manager, …)

Comment: Just some pointers. If the ToolWindow style (which doesn't show an icon) is not suitable for you, you would either draw the window frame yourself, or you would have an invisible (main) dummy window whose icon is shown in the taskbar. The former approach becomes a piece of work if you need to properly support the different Metro/DWM/XP border styles. The later approach requires quite some wiring and wrangling with window messages (minimize/maximize/restore/close/etc. messages), to make the taskbar icon of the invisible window behave as if it would belong to the visible icon-less window.

Comment: Apparently, doing what you want is not possible. The icon in the taskbar is the one identifying the application and thus ShowIcon = false is applied there too. You can keep showing the icon in any case (even with ShowIcon = false) in the notification area via NotifyIcon.